# Update with result from CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.1

I want to update job date if any records is an earlier date. Trying to use CTE to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE job
    (jobid int4, jobdate date);

INSERT INTO job
    (jobid, jobdate)
VALUES
    (1, '2016-02-01'),
    (2, '2016-02-01'),
    (3, '2016-02-01'),
    (4, '2016-02-01')
;

CREATE TABLE rec
    (recid int4, recjob int4, recdate date);

INSERT INTO rec
    (recid, recjob, recdate)
VALUES
    (1,1,'2016-02-01'),
    (2,2,'2016-01-01'),
    (3,3,'2016-02-01'),
    (4,4,'2016-02-01')
;
```

Job number 2 have a record dated earlier than the job date. So I want to update this job with the record date.

```
WITH      cte AS
          (SELECT jobid,least(min(recdate),jobdate)
FROM      job
LEFT JOIN rec ON recjob=jobid
GROUP BY  jobid,jobdate
HAVING    least(min(recdate),jobdate)<jobdate)
```

Selecting the CTE shows correct that job 2 should be updated

```
SELECT * FROM cte
```

But updating gives an error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "cte"

```
UPDATE job 
SET    jobdate=cte.date 
WHERE  jobid IN (SELECT jobid FROM cte)
```

SQLFiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e9ae6/8

I have never used CTE with `UPDATE`, so I need some help to understand this.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Try your `UPDATE` with the following syntax;

```
UPDATE job
SET jobdate = cte.date
FROM cte
WHERE job.jobid = cte.jobid
```

Comment: Please note that sometimes it's worth trying it with a CTE, as explained in the answer below by simPod. On some (big) tables, using one over the other can yield great performance benefits.

Answer (score 70):

The syntax is as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM ...
)
UPDATE table_to_update
SET column_from_table_to_update = cte.some_column
FROM cte
WHERE table_to_update.id = cte.id
```